# Trouble in deploing Solr on Tomcat and Debian

Tags: debian, tomcat, solr, installation

We have a Solr index application. It works very well on Lubuntu 10.10 (that's my local linux machine).
But I could'n run it in hoster Debian 2.6.26-15lenny3 (gcc version 4.1.3 20080704 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.2-25)). I think that configs are fine, because tomcat admin see solr (with running status "false") and on Lubuntu it work's.
In catalina log file there is this mistake:

```
Jan 31, 2011 7:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : /home/myname/solr/example/webapps/solr.war
 at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:130)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4249)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4418)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:624)
 at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Jan 31, 2011 7:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jan 31, 2011 7:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jan 31, 2011 7:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 31, 2011 7:09:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/solr] has not been started
```

Meanwhile, on (default) Jetty Solr (just installed) starting to work. Also, It maybe useful to say, that I've got some difficulties with installing Java and Tomcat on Debian. I had to use testing repositories to install tomcat6.

When I'm trying to manually start solr with jetty from shell

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
 at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:166)
 at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
 at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

Thank's for your help.